# How does Firebase rtdb query on a range of strings using orderByKey, startAt, endAt?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase query that looks like this:

```
this.db.object(`...irrelevent`).query
      .orderByKey().startAt(startVal).endAt(`${endVal}\uf8ff`).once('value').then(res => {
        if (res.val()) {
          // value returned
        }
      });
```

The structure of the area I'm querying looks like this

[image: Structure of Data]

Based on the documentation found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) when using the order by key function it first trys to sort the keys as numbers then lexicographically. As you can see in the image my keys are strings.

When `startVal = "0015"` and `endVal = "0060"` the query doesn't quite work as it returns this `{0000-0015: "a", 0015-0075: "-M-BCseCnboNM9zB3o5S"}`. From my understanding it should not be returning the first property of the object but when I make set `startVal = "0795"` and `endVal = "0810"` it returns:

```
{0000-0015: "a"
0015-0075: "-M-BCseCnboNM9zB3o5S"
0150-0240: "-M-BCxH9URUtYQg06wXE"
0300-0360: "-M-BD-YIAXO2FMVac0PW"}
```

This doesn't seem correct to me as it should return nothing because there exists no data between strings that startAt "0795" and  endAt "0810".

My goal is to be able to pass in a startVal such as "0000" and an endVal such as "0030" and it return

```
{0000-0015: "a"
0015-0075: "-M-BCseCnboNM9zB3o5S"}
```

Can someone maybe set my understanding straight on how the startAt and endAt queries work when querying for a range of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're seeing some sort of array coercion going on here.

I tested with this JSON:

```
{
  "0000-0015": "a",
  "0015-0075": "-M-BCseCnboNM9zB3o5S",
  "0150-0240": "-M-BCxH9URUtYQg06wXE",
  "0300-0360": "-M-BD-YIAXO2FMVac0PW",
  "key-0000-0015": "a",
  "key-0015-0075": "-M-BCseCnboNM9zB3o5S",
  "key-0150-0240": "-M-BCxH9URUtYQg06wXE",
  "key-0300-0360": "-M-BD-YIAXO2FMVac0PW",
}
```

And this code:

```
function query(start, end) {
  ref.orderByKey().startAt(start).endAt(end)
  .once('value').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(`startAt("${start}").endAt("${end}"): ${snapshot.numChildren()} result(s)`)
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      console.log(`"${child.key}"`)
    });
  });
}

query("0000", "0015");
query("0000-", "0015~");
query("0015-", "0060~");
query("key-0000", "key-0015");
```

And the output I got was:

```
startAt("0000").endAt("0015"): 0 result(s)
startAt("0000-").endAt("0015~"): 2 result(s)
  "0000-0015"
  "0015-0075"
startAt("0015-").endAt("0060~"): 1 result(s)
  "0015-0075"
startAt("key-0000").endAt("key-0015"): 1 result(s)
  "key-0000-0015"
```

All but that first result look correct, which is why I think the numbers are somehow being converted by (unpadded) array indices (so `0` instead of `"0000"`), which then doesn't work.

I'd recommend always prefixing numeric keys with an alphanumeric string, to prevent this sort of behavior, as I've done with the `key-` prefix above.

For my full testbed, see: https://jsbin.com/roluhip/2/edit?js,console

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your response. When I try the value `startAt("key-0030")`  and `endAt("key-0045")` I would expect it to return `"key-0015-0075": "-M-BCseCnboNM9zB3o5S"` as the startAt and endAt values are inside the bounds of the values of that key. Unfortunately it doesn't return anything. Any advice on that?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how Firebase queries work. They have no knowledge of the structure of your key, and purely perform a lexicographical order and sort operation. Lexicographically `key-0015` is not between `key-0030` and `key-0045`, so it won't be returned.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help!